# .net Core Trouble Instantiating Repository Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have the following Repository class:

```
public class TestRepository
{
    private readonly MyDbContext db;

    public TestRepository(MyDbContext context)
    {
        db = context;
    }

    public Test GetTest(int Id)
    {
        return db.Test.Find(Id);
    }
}
```

How do I instantiate the class from my controller?

When I try:

```
TestRepository repo = new TestRepository(MyDbContext);
```

I get the error that MyDbContext is a type which is not valid in the given context.  So I'm wondering what parameter I'm suppose to pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need change this

```
new TestRepository(MyDbContext);
```

for that

```
new TestRepository(db);
```

Best approach is use DI everywhere where you can.

You can register your repository classs in your DI container and call your method on that given instance.

Add this in your `startup.cs`

```
services.AddScoped<TestRepository>();
```

And use it in your controller

```
private readonly TestRepository _testRepository;

public IndexController(TestRepository testRepository)
{
    _testRepository = testRepository;
}
```

[Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1)
[Service lifetimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1#service-lifetimes)